# relocate dialog box after automatic resize in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dialog box that displays a dynamic-sized form. I currently get the dialog box to resize automatically with the following code. What I would like it to do is to auto relocate the dialog box after resize event occurs. This is because the dialog box resizes its width, and I would like it to remain centered in the page afterword.

```
  $("#form-div").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",
      resize: "auto",
      modal: true
  });

  $("#show-form-button").click(function() {
      $("#form-div").dialog("open");
  });
```

Edit:

Just to be clear

The dialog box displays a form. After the form is displayed, additional fields may be added to the form, causing it to no longer fit in the original dialog box. The " resize: 'auto' " option automatically takes care of this and resizes the dialog box. I want the dialog box to be centered after it is auto-resized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs there is a resizeStop hook after resizing is complete.  So you should be able to do something like this:

```
$("#form-div").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",
      resize: "auto",
      modal: true,
      resizeStop: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery(this).dialog('option','position','center');
      }
 });

 $("#show-form-button").click(function() {
     $("#form-div").dialog("open");
 });
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it works when I manually resize the dialog, but not if I have it auto resize.
The best solution I have come up with is watching for the form to finish resizing and then calling $("#form-div").dialog('option','position','center').
Auto relocate via the dialog's setup, if resize is set to auto, does not seem to be doable as no event is actually fired.

Comment: @Curtor: Can you explain what is causing the dialog box to resize?  Is it auto-resizing to contain content that is added to it after it is initially created?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The dialog box displays a form. After the form is displayed, additional fields may be added to the form, causing it to no longer fit in the original dialog box. The "resize: 'auto'" option automatically takes care of this and resizes the dialog box, but does not fire any event.

Comment: @Curtor:  This thread contains the code for a jQuery plugin event that fires when the content of an element changes.  Perhaps you could bind that to your form container and have the callback function do the resizing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449666/create-a-jquery-special-event-for-content-changed