# How to alert ,when div content changes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I want to give a alert message,when div content changes.

Is there any listener provided by jquery api for div element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html element content change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534955/html-element-content-change-event)

Comment: DIV is not an editable element. What exactly is causing the div content to change? Or are you using the contentEditable attribute?

Answer (score 17):

Bind the dom modification events -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test_div').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
        alert('Changed');
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks... This is what i needed... But I got one more issue here. my span tag is presented inside iframe. So it is not working:(