# CSS "breakpoints" on height of containers

Tags: css, height, breakpoints

Is there an elegant way to set breakpoints, of sorts, on height of containers.

**Example:**

Say you have a div and a min-height is set at say 100px. As soon as the content gets too much it doesn't just grow, but grows by another 100px and when the content eventually gets to the bottom of the 200px extend the height by another 100px.

Has anyone do anything like this before?

Comment: @media break points are based on screen size rather than the size of elements. CSS doesn't really have any other conditional logic that I'm aware of. Sounds like a job for JS to me.

Comment: I've provided a general jQuery solution that should do this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible only using CSS, but you can use javascript:

html:

```
<div id='div'>hello</div>
```

javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var height = 0;
div.style.height = height + "px";

while(div.scrollHeight > div.clientHeight){
    height += 50;
    div.style.height = height+"px";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fa7d0/JkT7R/

Answer (score 1):

I found your question very interesting so i took the *grow* bit literally and created a fiddle where content changes is handled and the containing div is increased either in width or height by a defined threshold.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tvswj/1/

The main idea is that you'll only have to listen for DOM changes and then run a jQuery function as such:

```
// Trigger the resize function on content change
$(myDiv).bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function () {
    $(this).breakpointResize(threshold);
});
```

If you find it useful, please go ahead and use it and modify as you want.

Credits for DOM events: [How to alert ,when div content changes using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672529/how-to-alert-when-div-content-changes-using-jquery)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it was only height. This does width too :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use container style height: auto ! Important; and min-height: 100px; width: 100%;