# Add attribute to all newly created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

For example add to all new links attribute `target` with value `_blank` or to all new `<div>`s attribute `title` with random value. Any ideas except `setTimout()`?

**UPD**: I need something like `.attrGlobal()`. <s>[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18366780/712308) answer allows to do that only with links and their attribute `target`</s>, but how to do that with all elements and all their attributes?

**UPD2**: Trying `MutationObserver` as [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366674/add-attribute-to-created-elements#comment26967477_18366674) but firefox freezes when clicking on add button http://jsfiddle.net/1337/wvfkc/5/.

Comment: what do you mean with "new links"? added dynamically?

Comment: And what does setTimeout have to do with it?  How are these elements being added?  Please show us the code.

Comment: And how are you creating these elements ?

Comment: @Sergio dynamicly created.

Comment: @ancap, how to you add them to the html? ajax with `.append()`, `.html()`, or?

Comment: You need some way to signify that they are new elements. maybe add a class to them upon creation and use that class as a starting point

Comment: You're looking for `MutationObserver`.

Comment: @Sergio doesn't metter. If element somehow created i need to add to him attribute with random value.

Comment: @ancap How do you create the element and when?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to just add the attribute whenever you create the element, that's why we're asking how you're creating the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution.

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
  $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
  $("div").attr("title", Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
});

observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true
});
```

[**`jsfiddle.net`**](http://jsfiddle.net/1337/Lcybj/21/)

In options you need `subtree: true` always, and if you changes attributes do not add to options `attributes: true` because `MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {` will go into the eternal cycle and browser freezes.

Comment: +1 I have having a hard time understanding why Firefox kept freezing when I had 'attributes: true' in the observer block! Now detecting changes is a piece of cake!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like is explained in this answer. [jQuery: Is there a way to automatically add attributes to dynamically generated HTML, in the same way that live() works with events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652672/jquery-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-add-attributes-to-dynamically-generated)

Since `.live` is deprecated, use `.on` instead.

Use `.on` to accomplish what you are looking to do with the links like so

```
$('a').on("click", function(e) {
   $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Except that `.live` has been deprecated, so use `.on()` -- almost identical.

Comment: `.live()` deprecated LOL. But I expected this answer.

Comment: ops this not work with newly created [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/1337/VC9dr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you add the new elements so jQuery can find them. To answer more precise we would need to know also the parent of the elements and if there are other elements that should not get changed.

If you add by ajax, the best would be to put this code in the success function.

```
$('#parentDivID a').prop('target', '_blank'); //this changes the atributes of all a element
$('#parentDivID div').prop('title', Math.floor(Math.random()*1000); //give random nr to title
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're trying to do?
(assuming clicking a button inserts new elements)

```
function setAttrs() {
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
    $('div').attr('title', new Date().getTime());
}
$(function() {
    setAttrs();
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').append('<div>text</div> <a href="//google.com">google</a>');
        setAttrs();
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ztjX8/)

Comment: What if content added but nothing was clicked? What if something clicked but content added async?

Comment: the `setAttrs` function just needs to be called whenever the content is added. if it is added asynchronously, then the function call should be executed in the success callback function of the ajax request.