# Check if p:fileUpload component contains any file to upload, to change background

Tags: javascript, css, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces **p:fileUpload** (primefaces 3.5) to upload various files. I want to check if the field, where are chose files shown and ready to be uploaded, contains any files. Depends on it change background. Maybe with javascript?

```
<p:fileUpload
    id="fileUploadComponent"
    mode="advanced"
    dragDropSupport="true"
    uploadLabel="Process"
    label="Choose files"
    widgetVar="fileUploadWidget"
    multiple="true"
    styleClass=""
    onstart="setUploadFilesCount()"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|odt|ods|doc|docx|csv|xlsx|xls|txt)$/"
    fileUploadListener="#{documentsBean.uploadAll}" >
</p:fileUpload>
```

Also fileUpload has dragDropSupport true, so whenever files are drag & droped i want to change background aswell as when i chose file with button.

Then  how can i set the styleClass of the upload field. Now i have it like this:

```
div.fileupload-content.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-bottom {
   min-height: 450px;
   background: url("../resources/images/uploadBackground2.png") 0 0 no-repeat !important;
   background-position: center center !important;}
```

How can i achieve it pls?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach an event on the generated file list.

Primefaces' FileUpload with your configuration generates this HTML :

```html
<div class="ui-fileupload-content ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <div class="ui-messages ui-widget ui-helper-hidden" style="display: none;">
        <div class="ui-messages-error ui-corner-all">
            <a class="ui-messages-close" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a><span class="ui-messages-error-icon"></span>
            <ul>
                <!-- HERE ARE YOUR FILES WITH "ERROR" FLAG (<li></li>) -->
            </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    <table class="ui-fileupload-files">
         <tbody>
              <!-- HERE ARE YOUR FILES WITH "OK" FLAG (<tr></tr>) --> 
         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So, you just have to attach an event to these two elements whom can detect HTML change, and trigger a custom function. This function will have to check for node count or HTML content and act accordingly (add/remove your CSS classes).

To do so, there are a few methods :

1 - DOM Events (deprecated, not cross-browser - see : http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) :

```
$('.myElement').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

2 - Custom event with timer (Fastidious but works - see : [Create a jQuery special event for content changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449666/create-a-jquery-special-event-for-content-changed)) :

```
$('.myElement').bind('contentchange', function() {
    // Your code here
});

(function(){

    var interval;

    jQuery.event.special.contentchange = {
        setup: function(){
        var self = this,
            $this = $(this),
            $originalContent = $this.text();
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                if($originalContent != $this.text()) {
                    $originalContent = $this.text();
                    jQuery.event.handle.call(self, {type:'contentchange'});
                }
            },100);
        },
        teardown: function(){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    };

})();
```

3 - Same as previous but with declaring a jQuery method (see : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/)

4 - With a Mutation Observer :

```
mainArea = document.querySelector(".myElement");
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
DocumentObserver = new MutationObserver(function() {
   // Your code here
});
DocumentObserverConfig = {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true};
DocumentObserver.observe(mainArea, DocumentObserverConfig);
```